# Does Typescript transpilation handle transpiling ES6 to ES5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am writing an app using Angular 2 and TypeScript. I want to use a js method (particularly 'filter' for arrays) which is supported by IE 11+, Chrome 45+, etc.
Will my code be able to run on older browsers? As Typescript transpiles to vanilla js, I am not sure what it does with ES6 features.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) is compatible with IE 9+ and all other browsers. It was not introduced with ES6

Comment: Note that this kind of method can be added by polyfills, too; you don't necessarily need transpilation.

Comment: @nicovank ok, but the question is still valid. I want to know in general, not that particular function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp indicates IE12 and avobe (I think that'd be Edge)

Comment: @AlejandroB. _Side Note:_ [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/) is notorious for having incorrect information. As far as references go, it's safer to lean on the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org) for information like this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

TypeScript allows you to use new *language features* from ES6 and it will transpile those language features to ES5; however, it does not add polyfills for *built in functions* that exist in ES6, but don't exist in ES5.

If you are using built in functions that only exist in ES6 and are targeting ES5, then you will need to include the necessary polyfills in order for the code to work in ES5 environments.

**Example**

For example, `fill` is a new function found on `Array`'s prototype in ES6.

```
const result = ["first", "second"].fill("all");
```

When you target ES6 everything is fine. The compiler will include *lib.es6.d.ts* with the definition for `fill` and not complain because it assumes you will be running the code in ES6 environments where the `fill` function exists.

When you target ES5, however, it won't include *lib.es6.d.ts* and will tell you that function doesn't exist in ES5 environments:

> error TS2399: Property 'fill' does not exist on type 'string[]'.

To fix that, you'll need to add `fill` to the `Array<T>` interface in a definition file in your project:

```
interface Array<T> {
    fill(value: T, start?: number, end?: number): this;
}
```

And include a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill). Or use something that does it automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can if you set tsconfig.json to target ES5

set `target: "ES5"` in tsconfig.json compiler options or `--target ES5` for CLI

As for built-in features of ES6, IDK, but I would add the babel-loader to webpack, grunt, gulp, etc, to automatically polyfill those features.